# SQL Insert Into leaves some columns null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to populate a temporary table with average data from another table. The temporary table has 2 columns. Each column of the temporary table should be populated with data from the old table that has a specific value in a column. This is the "tag index" column in the old table and it ranges from 1 to 2. So, I want the value (called val in code) in rows with a tag index of 1 in column 1 of temptable and val in rows with tag index of 2 in column 2.

I'm using `INSERT INTO` but it rotates inserting null values. My code and output are below and thanks for any help.

```
Insert INTO #temptable1 (V1)
    SELECT AVG(Val) FROM FloatTable_Z
     WHERE TagIndex=24


Insert Into #temptable1 (V2)
      SELECT AVG(Val) FROM FloatTable_Z
      WHERE TagIndex=26
```

## temptable1

```
2.06 NULL
NULL 2.08
1.78 NULL
NULL 1.99
''    ''
```

It repeats the pattern of inserting the value and inserting null for all of my data.

Again thanks for any help or comments!

Comment: Just to add some clarification. V1 and V2 are column names in temporary table. Also the output isn't in the format I intended. It is alternating between V1 and V2

Comment: Also, Its running in a while loop

Comment: It's generally best to avoid a while loop in which SQL statements are run. There is almost always a better way to do it with a one or two SQL statements en masse. If you share the loop or explain what you are doing, we may be able to help more.

Comment: When you say it's alternating, what are you expecting? Every time you ask a database to insert a row, it inserts a whole row. No database follows a logic of "oh, this subsequent insert statement inserts a value for column x and that column was blank last time an insert was done, I'll update the existing row's null column x with this new value" - that modus operandi makes zero sense

Answer (score 3):

When you run an `INSERT` you insert one row. You run two inserts (one inserting into one field, and the other into another field) and you have still inserted two rows. Two inserts, two rows. You can think of it like: `INSERT` is the CREATE in CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete)

A record/row in a SQL table is a bunch of related fields. So if you create a new record and you want to populate another field in that record afterwards (because the new value is related to the old value and they should be in the same record) then you would need to perform an `UPDATE` statement, not a second `INSERT`.

However, in this case it would be best to do this in one insert like:

```
Insert INTO #temptable1 (V1, V2)
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN TagIndex = 24 THEN VAL END),
    AVG(CASE WHEN TagIndex = 26 THEN VAL END)
FROM FloatTable_Z
```

Comment: I have doubts about that `CASE`... It will return just the `val` on each row with `TagIndex = n`, right? I'd suggest `AVG(CASE...` instead, but that won't average properly no matter what you set `ELSE` to.  I think you need subqueries.

Comment: @AaronDietz I suppose you're right. I believe the avg(case) omitting the else would work fine though.

Comment: Cool, I was thinking `NULL` would be considered for the denominator part of the average but it makes more sense that it isn't.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I was pleasantly surprised :)

Comment: Oddly the `avg()` inside the CASE worked for the first column in the result set but returned 0 for subsequent columns using the same logic. Mysql is a strange beast.

Comment: Nulls don't participate in aggregates

Comment: It's not the same logic. Putting the avg inside the case means that average is only calculated in that case for that row. Putting the case inside the avg means the average of all applicable cases is calculated

Comment: JNevil I stand corrected... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/33276/0 also @CaiusJard I would have thought that too.

Comment: Granted, if the `CASE... AVG(val)... END` ever hits the `ELSE` (ie add `UNION SELECT 'y', 1` to my fiddle), it would return multiple rows and fail the insert.  But I'm blown away it would work like that at all.

Comment: If it helps you to think of aggregates and nulls: I call you over to my work desk. On it there are just 3 apples, nothing else (I don't do a lot at work, just eat apples. Anyhoo..). I say to you "count these" and you say 3. I say "but what about all the apple sized spaces around the apples? There are 3 apples and 1000 nulls on this desk." But realistically the count is 3, not 1003. Can't count a null. "and what's the average weight?" Each apple is 100g, but what do the 1000 null apple shaped spaces weigh? 0g? That drags the average down massively.. Nulls do not participate in aggregates

Comment: @Aarondeitz what do you find surprising about that query?

Comment: @CaiusJard I meant your second comment is actually incorrect... Surprisingly (at least to me) `CASE.. AVG(val)` will aggregate across the group and not only on each row...  Check out the fiddle I linked.  Anyway, I get the `NULL` with aggregation - always appreciate a good analogy though :)

Comment: The linked fiddle has only one row (the group is done, the average is calculated, the case examines the grouped value and finds a truth in the predicate, the average is displayed once because there is only one row), the sanity of "Putting the avg inside the case means that average is only calculated in that case for that row" is preserved. If you add a `union select 'y',10` the result set will have two rows, one of which is null (false predicate in case when; grouped value is not 'x')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179668/discussion-between-caius-jard-and-aaron-dietz).